# Account Sharing rule with Customer portal user?

Tags: customer-portal, sharing

How to create the Account sharing rule to customer portal user.
  I give Default Access for 1.Account is "Private"
                            2. Contact is "Control by Parent"

- I create the Account sharing rule rule type is  **Based on criteria**.
- Select the users to share with Public Groups to "All Customer Portal Users"
- Select the level of access for the users *Default Account, Contract and Asset Access" Read/Write.

But still I am do not get the Account records for Customer portal user. I don't want portal user see the contacta, so I give the minimum access to the account.

How to solve the sharing rule issue?

Comment: What version of SF do you have?

Comment: @kittu what kind license are you using?

Comment: hi i am using licencse Overage High Volume Customer Portal for customer portaluser..

Comment: @Saariko Thanks for your response i have Developer Sandbox.

Answer (score 1):

High volume customer portal users do not have access to the sharing model. They cannot be added to groups or sharing roles. From the documentation:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customer_portal_manage_users.htm&language=en#CPsharingrules

Answer (score 0):

Set the Organization Wide Defulat setting to "private" for contact.

Specifically; Click Setup and go to Security Controls > Sharing Settings. Click edit above the Organization-Wide Defaults list and make the change.